# How to use classes in the external jar files after importing

Tags: java, json, eclipse

I have tried importing jar files using and tried to use the class but still, I keep getting the error.

The way I've used to import jar files:
https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/eclipse-cookbook/0596007108/ch04s12.html

I am using eclipse as my java coding platform.

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String message = "B:1:2:N";
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
        String s = message.substring(0,1);
            if (s=="M"){
                try {
                    String[] values = message.split(":");
                    ArrayList list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(values));
                    Object[] arr = list.toArray();
                    jsonObj.put("map", arr[1]); // Set the first name/pair
                    jsonObj.put("obstacle", arr[2]);
                }
                catch(JSONException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (s=="B"){
                 try {
                     String[] values = message.split(":");
                     ArrayList list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(values));
                     Object[] arr = list.toArray();
                     String Center = "("+arr[1]+", "+arr[2]+")";
                     String dir = "d"+arr[3];
                     int y;int x;
                     String Head = new String();

                     switch (dir) {
                         case ("dN"):
                             y = Integer.valueOf((String) arr[2]);
                             y = y+1;
                             Head = "("+arr[1]+", "+y+")";
                         case ("dW"):
                             x = (Integer) arr[1];
                             x = x-1;
                             Head = "("+x+", "+arr[2]+")";
                         case ("dE"):
                             x = (Integer) arr[1];
                             x = x+1;
                             Head = "("+x+", "+arr[2]+")";
                         case("dS"):
                             y = Integer.valueOf((String) arr[2]);
                             y = y-1;
                             Head = "("+arr[1]+", "+y+")";
                     }
                     //"robotHead": "(2, 1)"
                     //"robotCenter": "(1, 1)"
                     //"BOT_POS:x:y:dir"
                     jsonObj.put("robotHead",Head); // Set the first name/pair
                     jsonObj.put("robotCenter", Center);
                 }
                catch(JSONException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else{
                try {
                    jsonObj.put("message", message);
                }
                 catch(JSONException ex) {
                     ex.printStackTrace();
                 }
             }
             String M = jsonObj.toString();
            System.out.print(M);
        }
    }
```

This is the error message I keep getting.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    JSONObject cannot be resolved to a type
    JSONObject cannot be resolved to a type
    JSONException cannot be resolved to a type
    JSONException cannot be resolved to a type
    JSONException cannot be resolved to a type

```
at test.MyClass.main(MyClass.java:13)
```

Comment: Note `if (s=="B")` is not how you compare Strings in java

Comment: If you are using an IDE (tagged Eclipse) these jar files need to be added to your *build path*

Comment: "catch(JSONException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }" In that line you can try to "catch(Exception ex)" and than can see if there is another problem.

Comment: @Nurhan - Read the question. *Unresolved compilation problems*

Comment: instead of (only) posting a link to the page where something is described, explain what you really tried - maybe someone can figure out what went wrong. Otherwise we can only check if the linked descripttion is correct or not (much probably it is)

Comment: Adding a screenshot of the Eclipse classpath will help here. It seems the project is not built in Eclipse yet. Check for any build path errors